# Trouble using Functions for Hangman game in C

Tags: c, function

I am trying to make a hangman gave using C Functions. I was able to make the game without using functions but now when i try to use functions i am running into a few problems.

The main problem i am having is in my displayWord() function. I need this function to print out the word to screen with all letters that have not been correctly guessed blanked out with an underscore.

~Header FiIles

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Constants. */
#define NUM_WORDS 50
#define ALPHABET_SIZE 26
#define GOOD_GUESS 0
#define BAD_GUESS 1
#define GAME_OVER 1
#define GAME_CONTINUE 0
#define MAX_GUESS 10
#define MAX_WORD_LEN 10

/* Function prototypes. */
int init(char* word);
void displayWord(char* word, int* guessedLetters, int* length);
int guessLetter(char* word, int* guessedLetters);
void displayHangman(unsigned wrongGuesses);
int isGameOver(char* word, int* guessedLetters, unsigned wrongGuesses);
void readRestOfLine();
```

~Main Code

```
#include "hangman.h"

/****************************************************************************
* Function main() is the entry point for the program.
****************************************************************************/
int main(void)
{
   char word[MAX_WORD_LEN + 1];
   unsigned wrongGuesses = 0;
   int guessedLetters[ALPHABET_SIZE] = {
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
   };
   int length = 0;

   int numLives = 10;
   int numCorrect = 0;
   int oldCorrect = 0;
   int lengthOfWord = 0;
   length = init(word);
   printf("length: %d\n", length);
   displayWord(word, guessedLetters, length);



   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


int init(char* word)
{
   srand(time(NULL));
   int randomIndex = rand() % 50;

   const char* words[NUM_WORDS] = {
      "array",      "auto",       "break",      "case",       "cast",
      "character",  "comment",    "compiler",   "constant",   "continue",
      "default",    "double",     "dynamic",    "else",       "enum",
      "expression", "extern",     "file",       "float",      "function",
      "goto",       "heap",       "identifier", "library",    "linker",
      "long",       "macro",      "operand",    "operator",   "pointer",
      "prototype",  "recursion",  "register",   "return",     "short",
      "signed",     "sizeof",     "stack",      "statement",  "static",
      "string",     "struct",     "switch",     "typedef",    "union",
      "unsigned",   "variable",   "void",       "volatile",   "while"
   };

    word = words[randomIndex];
    int lengthOfWord = strlen(words[randomIndex]);
    printf("Word: %s\n", words[randomIndex]);

    return lengthOfWord;



}

void displayWord(char* word, int* guessedLetters, int* length)
{

    int loopIndex;
    char gameWord[][1] = word;


    for ( loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < length; loopIndex++ ) {

        if(letterGuessed[loopIndex] == 1) {
            printf("%c",gameWord[0][loopIndex]);
        } else {
            printf("-");
        }

    }
}
```

I have no idea how to scan through my random word to print out the letters that have been guessed. I have tried a few different way from reading around the web and watching videos but i am really not sure. Please help.

Problem Code

```
void displayWord(char* word, int* guessedLetters, int* length)
{

    int loopIndex;
    char gameWord[][1] = word;


    for ( loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < length; loopIndex++ ) {

        if(letterGuessed[loopIndex] == 1) {
            printf("%c",gameWord[0][loopIndex]);
        } else {
            printf("-");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing to do is to compile with warnings turned on (e.g., -Wall if using gcc) ... it will catch things like your incorrect parameter types.

Comment: Please take tilme to read a good C programming book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First thing** to notice: in `void displayWord(char* word, int* guessedLetters, int* length)` you're accepting a `int` pointer named `lenght`, but in your main code you are passing a normal `int`.

**Second thing**, in the `displayWord()` you have a loop with the length of the length of the `word` string. So when the length is 8, your loop goes 8 times and so it does not check the whole `guessedLetters[]` array.

**Third thing** in your `init(char *word)` function, you are passing a pointer. In the scope of this function, the variable `word` is **a copy** of the original pointer so when you point it to other locations, it does not have any effect. So you probably want to change

```
 word = words[randomIndex];
```

to

```
 strcpy(word, words[randomIndex]);
```

Now to give you an example of a solution you can change your code like so:

```
void displayWord(char *word, int *guessedLetters, int length)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++ ){

        if(guessedLetters[word[i] - 97] == 1){
            printf("%c", word[i]);
        }else{
            printf("-");
        }   
    }
}
```

**[SEE DEMO](http://codepad.org/55lFzU45)**

What I did here is look in the `guessedLetters` array to check if the current character is guessed or not. I subtracted 97 from the current character because that is the decimal [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) value of `'a'` (and so when the current character is `'a'`, it will look at index `0`).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistakes i made with the pointers.

I am still a bit confused now though.
My plan was to have the array guessedLetters[] represent the letters that have been guessed correctly.

So for example, if the word is 'Apple' and the user guesses 'a', the guessedLetters aray would scan the word and change the [0] spot to a '1'.
Which then displayWord() will check to see if a '1' is in any of the guessed spaces, so it prints out A----

Sorry i am really new to C

Comment: @Xarigizel did you try out my code? Because what you describe is exactly what my code does.

Comment: @Xarigizel and by the way, you didn't provide the code to scan user input and modify `guessedLetters[]` so that's something you need to build first (or just test with changing value's in the array manually)

Comment: Yep i put your code straight in and manually changed the values of guessedLetters[] to '1'.
But it still only printed out '-'. I am guessing i may of done something wrong when i copied your ode over, but i cant seem to work out what

Comment: Thank you so much, that one worked perfectly. I am not sure why it didn't work when i copied it over initially. I believe i am now equipped with the knowledge i need to finish off the rest of the game. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the code like this:

- Have one string "guess", as large as the answer string.
- Initially, fill the guess string up with blanks.
- When the user guesses a letter, iterate through the answer string and look for the letter there.
- If the letter is found, update `guess[i]` with the found letter. The user wins the "round".
- If the letter was not found in the answer string, the user loses the "round".
- When guess compares equal to answer, the game is solved.
- You don't necessarily need to save all of the user's guessed letters unless you need them for some other purpose, like displaying guesses or preventing the same guess twice.